# Please can someone identify this tree (UK)?

Tags: identification, trees

This UK garden tree has some kind of berries or seed pods but we can't find anything that matches it.

[image: Tree with berries(?) in UK garden.]

[image: Whole tree]

[image: Leaf and berry]

Comment: It looks a bit like an Amelanchier, but it is difficult to be sure.  Can you give a picture of the berries that you mention?

Comment: What color were the flowers? And were they of an unusual form?

Comment: Are you able to add a picture of the whole tree, as well as another, clearer, better lit close up of the leaves and any berries - its quite difficult to see detail in the photo you've provided because of the light levels, which show dappled sun but is  otherwise quite dark.

Comment: Hi @Stephen, welcome! Those look like underripe almonds, but again it's hard to be sure without clearer photos of the leaves and so on. If you get a chance to add some more snaps, remember you are encouraged to [Edit](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/52531/edit) your question to improve it as much as possible.

Comment: The extra pictures rule out it being an Amelanchier.

Answer (score 1):

Black walnut is my best guess which will stain your hands for days and days so get some rubber gloves.